# Move Module block to new location

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, xml

I'm trying to update a website that's had about 5 different development agencies on it and it started as a theme. I've added a new module that adds a bunch of blocks to the `product.info` Reference. I've managed to clear out the remaining junk from other developers that has been placed in there with similar funcitonality.

The block is being called by `$this->getChildHtml('product_type_data')` along with some other required blocks. so I want to move the block to a new section of the page, It needs to go somewhere where there are no other blocks. It's been so long since I touched Magento that I can't remember how to do this, or the Magento term for creating a new childHtml section where I need it. I know i need to be unsettling the block From it's old location and setting it to the new one, but without a area to put it in I'm kind of stuck.

**Module XML**

```
...

<PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>
    <update handle="product.info.simple"/>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="outofstocknotification/view" name="view" as="view"  />
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_simple>

...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can unset the block by using:

```
<action method="unsetChild">
    <alias>block.name</alias>
</action>
```

This will unset the child (as outlined by the method name) you could then add the block to the new reference:

```
<action method="append">
    <block>block.name</block>
</action>
```

Comment: How would that work in my example XML because I have tried that with about 30 different combinations of names and aliases that I can come up with and spent hours researching how to do this online with no luck.

Comment: so where did you want to move  the block `product_type_data` to? Is it inside the `product.info`?

Comment: Ideally to a new custom reference inside content, which is my issue as I can't find a up to date example of doing that.

Comment: You might have to redefine the block yourself. So on your `local.xml` or `theme.xml` add the full block output. e.g
```
<reference name="custom">
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml"/>
</reference>
```